# Loss of Detail and Unwanted Color changes when saving plt.imshow render as a np.array

Tags: image, matplotlib

Hi everyone this problem has been giving me a headache.

So I have a np.array (size of 2500x500) with values ranging from 0 to 2.95. I've plotted this with plt.imshow with inferno colormap and the render is perfect.

However, I want to save the render itself as a np.array (which would then have 3 rgb channels instead of 1). When I do this with matplotlib.cm.inferno(#my np.array), and when I plt.imshow this again, I get a different result.

I would be really grateful if someone can help me to get to the bottom of this.

[This is the image I'm trying to save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkLhH.png)
[This is the image I end up with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSJ0K.png)

Here is the code I tried

```
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib.cm import inferno


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,12))
img = ax.imshow(inference_map, cmap='inferno')
norm = Normalize(vmin=inference_map.min(), vmax=inference_map.max())
plt.axis('off')  
plt.show()

rgb_array = inferno(norm(inference_map), bytes=True)[:, :, :3]
# Display the RGB array as an image
plt.figure(figsize=(4,12))
plt.imshow(rgb_array)
plt.axis('off')  
plt.show()
```

Additionally, I also tried to change BGR to RGB but to no avail

Comment: Can you provide a dummy/reproducible dataset?